# Does VS's Diagnostic Tools measure the total Process Memory or the current Process Memory

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, visual-studio-2019

Does the Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools measure the total memory used by an application's threads, or its current memory currently in use?

I've got an application that reads data in from a 34 megapixel camera at 3 frames per second. The math comes out that it processes 288 MB per second, or about 17 GB per minute. With this in mind, the application obviously consumes a lot of data, once it starts collecting the camera frames. I have had my eyes glued to the Diagnostics Tools for a bit, for reasons you can see below:

[image]

I've let the application run with the performance profiler for about 3 minutes, and it ends up reporting a total process memory of about 31 GB, as you can see below:

[image]

My laptop only has 16 GB of RAM, so at first glance I think the picture above basically answers my question. However, just past the 2:30min mark you can see a sharp decline in the Memory, which doesn't make sense (I don't believe anything changed in how the program was running). Also, when I opened up the task manager I could see my application was using about 9 GB of memory, prior to shooting down to about 3 GB of memory around the 2:30min mark.

With all of that in mind, what is the Process Memory really measuring?

---

Because the solution was buried in the comments in the accepted answer, I'll summarize the solution here, to my overall problem of why my program was using so much memory. It had to do with a bug where I was not disposing of Bitmaps. Bitmaps are unmanaged memory; if you fail to dispose of them before they go out of scope, they continue living in memory (outside of your Garbage Collector) until a threshold is reached in the number of unmanaged objects. Only when that threshold is hit, will the unmanaged objects get deleted. That is what was happening in my program, when it dipped from ~31 GB of memory to about 5 GB of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, just past the 2:30min mark you can see a sharp decline in the
>   Memory, which doesn't make sense (I don't believe anything changed in
>   how the program was running).

Garbage collection is a complicated process which can affect your application performance. So GC has been optimized to trigger only when there is a memory pressure over is threshold.

When there is a memory pressure, garbage collection process kicks off and clears unnecessary memory allocations. This is the Garbage collection normal behavior.

> Does VS's Diagnostic Tools measure the total Process Memory or the
>   current Process Memory?

It measures your application's current memory usage. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019) is a tutorial to understand VS memory tool.

The fact that it releases most of the memory usage after the garbage cycle means that there are no big memory leaks.

Redgate Ants memory profiler can show more details (Retensoin graphs etc). Here is a video that explains memory leaks bit clearly. https://documentation.red-gate.com/amp10/worked-example/video-tutorials

> Is it possible to limit the amount of disc space available to a C#
>   program? I'm wondering if I could force C# to hold on to memory for a
>   shorter period of time.

You can call [GC.Collect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.8) to force an immediate garbage collection after a memory expensive process. However, this is not recommended at all unless there is a really good reason for that. Garbage collect uses heuristic algorithms to optimize its behavior. You don't have to worry about this usually. One thing is MAKE SURE YOU DISPOSE ALL THE DISPOSABLE INSTANCES before they go out of scope. That can help to release memory with less garbage cycles.

Comment: Does memory usage mean RAM usage, or can it mean disc space too?

Comment: @Max: RAM and virtual memory(paging) usage

Comment: Is it possible to limit the amount of disc space available to a C# program? I'm wondering if I could force C# to hold on to memory for a shorter period of time.

Comment: @Max: You can call GC.Collect to  force an immediate garbage collection after a memory expensive process. However, this is not recommended at all unless there is a really good reason for that. Garbage collect uses heuristic algorithms to optimize its behavior. You don't have to worry about this usually. One thing is MAKE SURE YOU DISPOSE ALL THE DISPOSABLE INSTANCE. That can help to release memory with less garbage cycles.

Comment: Right, I had researched GC for C#; obviously C# does make use of auto-GC strategies, but it is possible to manually call for GC to occur (Microsoft recommends only using this for testing purposes, not in production code). Upon further investigation, I discovered an issue from using Bitmaps! Using Redgate ANTS, I discovered that at a point in time where I had 32 GB of unmanaged data, 29 GB was coming from gdiplus. Strange, as I'm creating / using my Bitmap in a using statement.

Comment: @Max: I guess, there is no issue if they all are getting cleared after the garbage collection.

Comment: I dug much deeper into my application and found separate code that was storing a Bitmap and NOT deleting old bitmaps before reassigning a new one. I added a call to .Dispose() and reran ANTS; my application no longer scales up past 2-4GB. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Max: Yes, if there is something Disposable, it's a very good practice to dispose them before they go out of scope. That helps to release memory sooner. When you take a snapshot on ANTS memory profiler, it executes GC.Collect.